# Extracting addresses from wallet.dat without knowing password

Tags: wallet.dat

It is a pink flash with a comb icon on it. It contains a wallet.dat file. I have read about pywallet or syncing with bitcoin core, but I am an amateur and apprehensive. Is that a good route? Is there an easy way to identify the wallet address to check activity?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Photo below. [image: cold wallet found in cave]

Comment: In my part of the world a lost wallet remains the property of the person who lost it and honest people finding lost wallets are expected to take the found wallet to local police (or maybe property owner) . My advice would be to avoid stealing money from someone else's wallet.

Comment: Plugging “lost” devices found in the wild into your computer is a great way to catch malware.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The police (enforcers of fiat law) were not the rightful owners over the wallet either and given the state of the law they would rather take all of the funds off of it before the rightful owner (who may have purposefully 'lost' their keys you never know) . @ Murch while its true that plugging in unknown hardware devices is dangerous on devices you actually use, its plenty safe to plug one in to a spare clean device that is disconnected from any access to your personal data. Which is advice that is more in line with the user's question.

Comment: Furthermore simply finding a wallet.dat file does not imply that this is a full wallet, the user may have very well had multiple backups of the wallet and moved their funds once they realized they had lost one of the copies. Simply assuming the worst in this situation seems irrational.